# Setting page number with fancy without lastpage package

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr, lastpage

I am using the following code to generate footer with fancy to show the page number

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markright{#1}{}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

This works in my local computer since I have the `lastpage` package installed. But I need to run LaTeX on the server where I don't have the `lastpage` and I don't have right to install the package. So is there any way to implement the same thing without the `lastpage` package?

Here I upload the complete code but I just find that if there is any \newpage command, it won't compile, is that any way to fix this?

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{
\markright{#1}{}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage/\pagenum{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
  \title{XXX}
  \author{YYY}
  \maketitle

  This is first page 
  %\newpage  % it won't compile if \newpage was there

  This is second page
  %\newpage % if won't compile if \newpage was there

  This is last page

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please notice that `\markright` takes only one argument and that the end-of-line after `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{` can insert a space into the output. Either put it in one line or add `%` at the end of the first line (to eat spaces).

Comment: And the problem is probably your typo in `\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage/\pagenum{LastPage}}`. You have the line there twice and the second one contains `\pagenum` instead of `\pageref`.

Comment: Use `\pageref` instead of `\pagenum`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Run latex on [`lastpage.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/lastpage/lastpage.dtx) to create `lastpage.sty`. Keep this in your working folder on the server; there is no need to install it.
2. Use the [`pageslts` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts) which emulates (and extends) [`lastpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage). Not only does it provide the `LastPage` reference, it also has `VeryLastPage`, in case of unprocessed floats `\AtEndDocument`.
3. Manually insert a label at the end of your document:

   ```
   \label{LastPage}
   ```

   If there are unprocessed floats, insert the `\label` as part of the last float.

Comment: thanks, it helps. Now I can compile it in the local folder. But still have one more question, I just updated my top post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like putting a page reference on the last page

```
\label{mylastpage}
```

After compiling twice, you should be able to get the right page.

I believe that there might be some circumstances where this might give you the wrong page number.  I'll look into it some more.